# Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop troubleshooting

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, visual-studio-express

Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop is displaying incorrectly.  When I open the program, it displays correctly but upon moving my cursor over links or images inside of the interface, they either expand to fill the whole window or the line itself blurs.
I'm running Windows 8.1.  I've run it in compatibility mode for XP, Vista, and 7.  I've run as administrator.  I've reinstalled and repaired. This error is easily reproducible and has occurred over the course of 3 days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like problems with your video driver to me. Do other WPF applications do this for you? Is there an updated version of your video driver available from the manufacturer?

Comment: My drivers are up to date.  VS express 2013 is the only program this happens on.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I just installed VS 2010 as well.  Same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can only guess that your video card vendor happens to maintain a bad driver (or Windows Update pushed a bad version to your machine).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2894215

The workaround is to disable hardware graphics acceleration and test again.

Comment: That might have fixed it.  Thank you so much.